# Does every locally constant function has finite image imply compactness?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a topological space,  $A$ be a subset of $X$. A function $f:A\to X$ is said to be 
locally constant if for every $x\in A$, there is an open neighborhood of $x$ such that $f$ is constant on the neighborhood. Suppose that the image of every locally constant function from $A$ to $X$ is a finite set. Is it true that $A$ must be compact?

Edit: If $A$ has only finitely many connected components, then we see that a locally constant function $f$ must be constant on each connected components, thus the hypothesis holds without $A$ being compact. Now if we exclude this case, we require that $A$ has infinitely many connected components, Does the above  hypothesis imply that $A$ is compact?

Comment: Infinitely many connected components don't suffice. If there is a point $p$ such that every neighbourhood of $p$ intersects all but finitely many of the components, then every locally constant function attains only finitely many values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at $X=\Bbb R$ with usual topology and $A=(0,1)$. More generally, already a subset $A$ with finitely many connected components would have the property, but not necessarily be compact.

Comment: @XiangYu no, this function is not continuous.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma If $A$ has infinitely many connected components (for example, $A$ is an infinite totally disconnected space), in this case, must $A$ be compact?

Comment: @XiangYu it is true that if $A$ does not have this property and $X$ is $T_1$, then $A$ is not compact.

Comment: Inverse images of points form a disjoint clopen cover.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks. Could tell me how to prove it?